# How to check if changing shared method would not break other branches that haven't merged in the main branch?

Tags: git, version-control

When I need to modify a shared method, I check the whole codebase and ensure my changes would not break things. However, those changes break another branch, and in case that branch is merged in codebase before my changes are, we have no way to notice the error immediately.

For now, my team keeps track of changes to critical methods on Slack, but I find it's quite tedious. Can someone suggest what can be a better workflow to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is to have and use a good testing infrastructure.  If for whatever reason your team can't or won't do this, then you are doomed to spend your days tediously coddling a brittle code-base.

When you merge your feature into the main branch (typically either `master` or `develop`, depending on your workflow), you perform the merge locally.  At that point you should be doing a build, and that build should be running an automated test suite, and if something that was merged into the codebase (but not yet available in your feature branch) interacts badly with the code on your feature branch, the test suite should be comprehensive enough that you can expect it to detect the problem.

That way, if the tests fail you know you need to do more work before the merge will be possible.  (Back out the merge, merge the main codebase back into your feature, continue developing on your feature branch until the issue is resolved and then try the merge again.)  Only when the tests pass should the merge of the feature into the mainline by pushed to origin.

Writing tests that can be run quickly enough to be part of the build, yet comprehensive enough to give good confidence, may be no easy task - especially if you have a sizable code base that hasn't been doing this.  But once it's done, you can move forward with greater confidence without relying on tedious manual communication of "high risk changes" among the team.

Comment: Seems not easy, but better in the long run. Thanks for your suggestion!